# Client side search on text change - when to send request?

Tags: javascript, typescript, request

I have a search engine for an entity, and it has many filters.
I am required to update the search results when the filters change.
Some filters are selected from dropdowns, others are text inputs.
What is the correct way to implement search on change, when the change can happen frequently as the user types?

Here are some possibilities:

- **When the input loses focus.** The problem: the user might type away some text and wait for the search to work, but it won't.
- **On each keystroke.** The problem is I'll flood the server with requests.
- **Wait x milliseconds after the last change in the input and then send the request.** The problem is the search might become slow for the user.

  What is the best approach?

Comment: Personally, for something with many elements that affect the filter, I'd have an update button and do nothing until it's clicked.

Comment: Are you writing on some framework or it's pure js?

Comment: @Leo Odishvili I'm writing the client in Angular 4

Comment: @Nimirium Okay, then you should probably use either some little timeouts, which will lead to some bad code or you can use RxJS framework where you can find debounceTime function. If you were working at angularjs(Angular 1) you will know debounce in model-options. And it's my opinion of course ;) I can write much more in answer if this is not enough

Answer (score 0):

You can either do keydown or keyup for inputs. If it's a dropdown menu you can use onchange.

Personally, I would recommend adding a minimum character limit so you're not hammering your resources.

For example

```
var foo = document.querySelector("#inputElement");
// Change your event listener to what you need.
foo.addEventListener("keyup", doSomeStuff);
function doSomeStuff(e){
    var input = e.value;
    // Rest of your function
}
```

You can learn about event listeners [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)